# Regex to match specific url only with https

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I can't wrap my head around regular expressions, so I woul kindly ask your help

I'm looking for a regular expression (compatible with IIS Url rewrite module) that can match the following test cases:

```
Regex should match http://projects.myurl.com.lol
Regex should match http://projects.myurl.com.lol/
Regex should match http://projects.myurl.com.lol/documents/etc
Regex should match projects.myurl.com.lol
Regex should match projects.myurl.com.lol/

Regex should match projects.myurl.com.lol/whatever

Regex should not match https://projects.myurl.com.lol
Regex should not match http://something.myurl.com.lol
Regex should not match blahblahblah
```

so far I got this

```
((http:\/\/)?(projects\.myurl\.com\.lol)+)*
```

but it's not passing my unit tests, can you point me to the right direction please? (not looking only for a correct regex, but for a reason why my regex wont work)

Answer (score 0):

I wolud do it like this:

```
^(?:http://|)projects\.myurl\.com\.lol.*$
```

Explanation:

**^** -> beginning of string (url)

**(?:http://|)** -> we are looking for http:// or nothing and the ?: is to make a non matching group (and probably can be ommited)

**projects\.myurl\.com\.lol** -> main part of the url your looking for

**.*** -> any character 0 or more times

**$** -> end of string (url)

Unfortunately I can't tell why your regex does't work because I have trouble figuring out what you wanted to achieve ;) Maybe you could try to "explain" your regex as I did?

Answer (score 0):

If your language support nagative lookbehind, try with:

```
(?<!https:\/\/)(http:\/\/)?(projects\.myurl\.com\.lol)((\/[^\/\n]+)+)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY1hM7/5)

where `(?<!https:\/\/)` is negative lookbehind for `https://` so all fragments which would match, but are preceded by `https://` would not be matched.

the last part `((\/[^\/\n]+)+)?` is optional if you want to match also `/.../...` part. If you language doesn't support positive lookbehind, you can use:

```
(\s|^)(http:\/\/|)?(projects\.myurl\.com\.lol)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY1hM7/4)

where `(\s|^)` stand for whitspace(if url is proceeded by some text) or beginning of a line(if url is in separate string or on beginning of string). 
Also you can add optional part here to capture `/.../...` part.

**Your regex fail because**, as you can [check here](https://regex101.com/r/fY1hM7/6), also can match:

- everywhere, as you use `*` quantifire on rest of regex(`(...)*`), which means zero or more times, so everything is optional and it also match points between letters, etc., without `*`:
- it still match `https://projects.myurl.com.lol` because the part after `//` is valid, so it match only this part. Case here is to ensure that regex will match only if http:// occur or url wouldn't be preceded by any words,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a common url with `https` only can be check with below regex

```
^(https:\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```